# How to get rid of Spring Neo4j startup warnings?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Spring Data Neo4j with Springboot, and the application works.

However, I have a raft of warnings on startup that I'd like to get rid of if possible.

```
2019-09-08 14:15:20.788  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.apache.commons.logging.Log.fatalEnabled
2019-09-08 14:15:20.789  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.apache.commons.logging.Log.errorEnabled
2019-09-08 14:15:20.790  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.apache.commons.logging.Log.infoEnabled
2019-09-08 14:15:20.790  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.apache.commons.logging.Log.debugEnabled
2019-09-08 14:15:20.790  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.apache.commons.logging.Log.traceEnabled
2019-09-08 14:15:20.791  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.apache.commons.logging.Log.warnEnabled
2019-09-08 14:15:20.796  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.parent
2019-09-08 14:15:20.796  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.environment
2019-09-08 14:15:20.797  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.classLoader
2019-09-08 14:15:20.797  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.displayName
2019-09-08 14:15:20.797  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.startupDate
2019-09-08 14:15:20.798  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.beanDefinitionCount
2019-09-08 14:15:20.798  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.autowireCapableBeanFactory
2019-09-08 14:15:20.798  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.beanDefinitionNames
2019-09-08 14:15:20.799  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.parentBeanFactory
2019-09-08 14:15:20.799  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.id
2019-09-08 14:15:20.799  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.applicationName
2019-09-08 14:15:20.801  INFO 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext  : No class information found in OGM meta-data for class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration so treating as simple type for SD Commons
2019-09-08 14:15:20.802  INFO 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext  : No class information found in OGM meta-data for class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder so treating as simple type for SD Commons
2019-09-08 14:15:20.805  INFO 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext  : No class information found in OGM meta-data for class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity so treating as simple type for SD Commons
2019-09-08 14:15:20.850  INFO 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext  : No class information found in OGM meta-data for class java.util.ArrayList so treating as simple type for SD Commons
2019-09-08 14:15:20.896  INFO 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext  : No class information found in OGM meta-data for class org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders so treating as simple type for SD Commons
2019-09-08 14:15:20.929  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.core.env.Environment.defaultProfiles
2019-09-08 14:15:20.929  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: org.springframework.core.env.Environment.activeProfiles
2019-09-08 14:15:20.932  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.initParameterNames
2019-09-08 14:15:20.932  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.virtualServerName
2019-09-08 14:15:20.932  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.classLoader
2019-09-08 14:15:20.932  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.filterRegistrations
2019-09-08 14:15:20.933  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.servletNames
2019-09-08 14:15:20.933  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.sessionTrackingModes
2019-09-08 14:15:20.933  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.contextPath
2019-09-08 14:15:20.933  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.defaultSessionTrackingModes
2019-09-08 14:15:20.934  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.majorVersion
2019-09-08 14:15:20.934  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.effectiveMinorVersion
2019-09-08 14:15:20.934  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.sessionCookieConfig
2019-09-08 14:15:20.934  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.effectiveSessionTrackingModes
2019-09-08 14:15:20.934  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.attributeNames
2019-09-08 14:15:20.935  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.serverInfo
2019-09-08 14:15:20.935  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.servletRegistrations
2019-09-08 14:15:20.935  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.jspConfigDescriptor
2019-09-08 14:15:20.935  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.servlets
2019-09-08 14:15:20.936  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.requestCharacterEncoding
2019-09-08 14:15:20.936  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.responseCharacterEncoding
2019-09-08 14:15:20.936  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.sessionTimeout
2019-09-08 14:15:20.936  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.minorVersion
2019-09-08 14:15:20.937  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.servletContextName
2019-09-08 14:15:20.937  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.ServletContext.effectiveMajorVersion
2019-09-08 14:15:20.938  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.FilterConfig.initParameterNames
2019-09-08 14:15:20.938  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.FilterConfig.servletContext
2019-09-08 14:15:20.939  WARN 10121 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : Owning ClassInfo is null for property: javax.servlet.FilterConfig.filterName
```

What is making it so unhappy?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I'm just filtering those at the moment :(

Comment: actually, I finally resolved it... :). I'll post an answer...

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue and after 2 days, I finally figured it out...

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
```

Then typically you'll have the username and password in your application properties:

```
spring.data.neo4j.open-in-view=false
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=xxx
```

You'll also have your enable call:

@EnableNeo4jRepositories

It seems that the Neo4j code is scanning all classes in your app by default, but you can override this behavior:

1. Create a config class and move your EnableNeo4jRepositories to there
2. Specify your repo base package
3. Specify your model base package

Now the Neo4j code knows to only scan the repo & model packages. Here is my config class for the Movie dataset:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages="org.xx.yy.movies.repositories")
public class MoviesDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() {
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new Builder()
                .uri("bolt://username:password@localhost:7687").
                build();
        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "org.xx.yy.movies.models");
    }
}
```

Note that you need to specify the username and password in the uri... this is still POC code, but I'm going to just pull them out of the spring.data.neo4j properties for productionalizing.

No more warning messages!

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem (SpringBoot 2.2.2 with dependency `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j`).  Got rid of the warning and narrowed scanning of entity/model classes by adding **both** annotations to the main `@SpringBootApplication` annotated application class:

```java
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("my.project.reposoitory")
@EntityScan("my.project.model")
```

Avoids the need for a separate `@Config` class / overriding SpringBoot auto config. See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference.getting_started.spring-configuration.boot).

**Update:**
Bumped the Spring Boot version to `2.2.4.RELEASE` as I was having problems returning any data from my `Neo4jRepository` declarative methods. Suspect this is tx related, will raise a defect.

Comment: I already had `@EnableNeo4jRepositories`  as per some setup tutorial. Adding `@EntityScan` as well got rid of the errors for me.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way i solved this error for my application was by adding below line in `application.properties` file

`logging.level.org.spring.data.neo4j.mapping.*=ERROR`